# Looking for a JavaScript band-aid

Tags: javascript

I have some code in a JavaScript file which is called at the bottom of my page near the closing  tag which really should be adjusted...

```
if(wa.URLchunk1 == "https://www.example.com/bla/") {
    wa.selectedLink = dojo.query ('.wcmLeftNavSelectedLink')[0].innerHTML;
    if(wa.selectedLink.indexOf('some text') != -1)
        wa.customPageName = wa.customPageName + 'some text/';
    else if(wa.selectedLink.indexOf('some other text') != -1)
        wa.customPageName = wa.customPageName + some other text/';
    else if(wa.selectedLink.indexOf('some other other text') != -1)
        wa.customPageName = wa.customPageName + 'some other other text/';
}
```

In most circumstances this code works fine for me but in some cases the wcmLeftNavSelectedLink class is undefined which breaks my code. Ideally the code should be adjusted to include logic to only set wa.selectedLink when that class exists. However, my problem is that I am no longer able to update this JavaScript file. My client put a code freeze in place and won't allow any more updates to site as it will be eventually phased out.

I do have a tag management platform in place so I am able to set new JavaScript further up in the page. **So my question is**, are there any clever work-arounds which will allow me to stop this code from firing when the wcmLeftNavSelectedLink class is undefined keeping in mind I can't change the code directly. I can only set new code before this code fires.

FYI, wa.URLchunk1 is set to nothing earlier on in this JS file so I can't just manually set it to something else unless there is a way to set a variable and not allow it to be changed afterward.

Comment: Just add a class further up if it doesnt exist - then the code shouldn't error out.

Comment: That's one of the oddest requests I saw recently. No offense, but tell the client if he want's the bug fixed you need to change the code. If you can't do that he'll have to live with it.

Comment: LOL Florian. Yeah, this client is one of those not so easy to deal with types. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add HTML before this JS, do so:

```
<span class="wcmLeftNavSelectedLink" style="display:none"></span>
```

If there's already a matching element, that one will be first `[0]`, and this will be ignored.

If *not*, this will match none of your cases, and so the code effectively does nothing.

Comment: I love when the solution is simple. Thank you Paul.